# Change background color tableview when selected, highlighting persisting

Tags: css, javafx

I want to change the color of the background of a tableView (javafx) when it's selected, but I have a little blue line (same color than the highlighting) which appears: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfN2H.png)

Here is my CSS code:

```
.table-view {
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}
.table-view .table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-body-color: #CEDAE3;
    -fx-background-color: #CEDAE3;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
.table-view:focused {
  -fx-background-color: transparent,-fx-box-border,-fx-control-inner-background;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Try setting `-fx-accent: transparent ;` for the `.table-view`.

Comment: It's working, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default style sheet, `modena.css`, has a rule

```css
.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell .table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-selection-bar, 20%);
}
```

This sets the `-fx-background` looked-up color in a cell in a selected row to `-fx-selection-bar` and the `-fx-table-cell-border-color` looked-up color to a color 20% lighter than it.

The `table-cell` defines its border color in terms of these via

```css
.table-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0.166667em; /* 2px, plus border adds 1px */
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-border-color: transparent -fx-table-cell-border-color transparent transparent;
    -fx-cell-size: 2.0em; /* 24 */
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}
```

Consequently, in a cell in a selected row, you see a right border defined by `-fx-selection-bar`.

The default setting for `-fx-selection-bar` is near the top of the style sheet:

```css
/* A bright blue for highlighting/accenting objects.  For example: selected
 * text; selected items in menus, lists, trees, and tables; progress bars */
-fx-accent: #0096C9;

/* ... */

-fx-selection-bar: -fx-accent;
```

Therefore, you can remove this border by redefining `-fx-accent` for the table view:

```css
.table-view {
    -fx-accent: transparent ;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rules to change the color of the outer and inner borders of a tableView :

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: black;
}
```